# Django not able to find the static files when using django-allauth

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings, django-staticfiles

When I use allauth, everything seems to work fine except that Django is now unable to find the static files. Without allauth all the static files are being rendered. the settings for allauth requires to add

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (

    "allauth.context_processors.allauth",
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account"
)
```

I did not have TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in my settings file earlier. Is there something that I am missing? How should I solve this problem. When I see the DEBUG console I can see it is trying to fetch the css file as

```
"GET /accounts/login/css/contact.css"
```

whereas it should be doing

```
"GET /static/css/contact.css"
```

Comment: Tell me the file (link) where call to "contact.css"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a default value for TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS and you're overriding that one. So now the default ones are missing. And one of them is "django.core.context_processors.static", which is why Django can't find your static files.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#template-context-processors for the default list. What you need is the following:

```
 TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
     "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
     "django.core.context_processors.debug",
     "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
     "django.core.context_processors.media",
     "django.core.context_processors.static",
     "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
     "allauth.context_processors.allauth",
     "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
     )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... Actually up til now I had not been using TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS and the thing were working fine... I have not understood the significance of TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, because everything works fine without that also, could you please explain what the reason is?

Comment: I don't know "allauth", so I also don't know what its context processors do. I'd assume it puts some 'account' in your templates' context. If you your self don't use that, you won't miss the lack of the context processor. You might want to check if allauth's own templates all work.

Comment: Is there a way how to get the default value in settings.py from a django module?

Comment: @PetrPeller: I guess you mean something like `from django.conf import global-settings`? That's the full default list of settings.

Comment: Deprecated (as in 2017): http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html --> `# Specify the context processors as follows:
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {    'context_processors': [  # Already defined Django-related contexts here   # allauth needs this from django            'django.template.context_processors.request',    ],  },  },]`